Ubuntu 24.04 Internal Microphone Not working
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on an Acer Aspire 5 with Realtek ALC256 and it seems that my internal microphone is not working. I was on a Slack call and I was told that all they could here was static. This image shows the microphones available in the sound settings. Even though the bar says that there is something happening in the microphone, this is just static.

When I run arecord -l, I get the following output:
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


The problem seems to be specific to Acer Aspires. This post fixes the issue when using the model aspire-headset-mic.
